# how to accessing gpio from another computer web server

Tags: gpio, web-server

i'm doing a project for face recognition with raspberry pi. but i want my web server is from my laptop and my raspberry pi just accessing the web app. the point is, all of stuff is done in my laptop web server. but i don't know how to send signal to raspberry gpio from another computer web server to raspberry pi ? does anyone has a solution ? pardon my english. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [pigpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) and run it as a daemon on the pi, you can run local Python code that access the GPIO port on the remote pi.

If you are new to this, you might also want to check out the [gpiozero project](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html).